# Can we detect font size or font family in mobile device in web project?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a project where I need to change font style and size according to user need like if the user's devices have large font-size than font-size of web pages also large.

For example, your android or ios device has base fonts-size like below

main heading - 18px
secondary heading - 16px
content - 14px

and your web main page
Font-size is

main heading - 16px
secondary heading - 18px
content - 12px

Now I want to detect the android or ios device font-size to change my web page font size.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Comment: @shrys I have already applied CSS with media queries but I am looking for font-size according to device font-size.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the actual rendered font when it's not defined in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7444451/how-to-get-the-actual-rendered-font-when-its-not-defined-in-css)

Comment: @A.Meshu I tried this but did not working for mobile to get the information.

Comment: @DharmeshMertwal can you share your code attempt?

Comment: @A.Meshu you have already mentioned on your above comment.

Comment: @DharmeshMertwal check my answer please

Answer (score 0):

(continuation from comments above).

```
var div = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]; // this will set the body tag as variable
// this taken from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7444724/6525081
function css( element, property ) { 
    return window.getComputedStyle( element, null ).getPropertyValue( property );
}
alert( css( div, 'font-size' ) );
```

Read more about getComputedStyle [here](http://%20https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

You can check similar fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4mxzE/)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, I have tried this. This code will get the font-size of particular div or element,
I am asking about my device native font size.

Comment: Using this code will get you the initial font-size that all elements will render from (the body of the document - as the browser display it). Once you have it you can decide what to do with it. What is your goal? If it will be 16px - than what?

Answer (score -3):

you should use media queries, this command is for you to define specific styles for certain screen sizes, follow a tutorial on how to use

Example:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  body {
    background-color: lightblue;
  }
}
```

[Complete tutorial here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

in case you want to change the source according to the size of the device source use the `rem`

it is a measure that takes as a base the size of the font configured in the browser

Example:

```
div{
   font-size: 1rem
}
```

[Here's the rem tutorial](https://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/font-size-with-rem)

Comment: Thank you but **I have already applied CSS with media queries but I am looking for font-size according to device font-size**

Comment: just use rem as described in the answer