# getComputedStyle Font Family returns multiple families

Tags: javascript

I'm using the `getComputedStyles` function to get the styles of a certain text element on a page. Whenever I try to get the font family, instead of getting a single font family name, I get multiple ones, especially the generic ones like Helvetica, SegoeUI, Noto, etc..
How can I get it to show me only the first font family?

I've tried using `.slice` and `fontFamily[0]` but that only gets me the first letter not the first element

**Code**

```
const getStyles = getComputedStyle(textElement);
const family = getStyles.fontFamily;
const newFont = family;

console.log(newFont);
```

Comment: Does this (unfortunately) answer your question? [How to get the actual rendered font when it's not defined in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13845553/283366)

Comment: I see. But no this doesn't really answer my question. I'm aware that in a case like this there might be no way of knowing the exact font that is being used from the list and I'm totally okay with that. What I simply want to know is how I can just display the very first font of that list, that's all I want...

Comment: What is the actual format you get? Is it a comma-separated list?

Comment: Yes, it is a comma separated list e.g. Inter, Arial, "Segoe UI", Noto.

Comment: Still no answer? @Phil

Comment: Split on comma? `str.split(", ")[0]`

Comment: Yup, works like a charm! Thanks mate